# python selenium webdriver doesn't work problem

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I made this program which is supposed to log in to text now sign in and call whoever I wanna call. Making it as efficient as possible. But when I run it the script works except the final value I don't know what the mistake is. But, I would appreciate any answers.

```
#imports
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass  import getpass

username = input('Enter in your username: ')
password = getpass('Enter your password: ')
number = input('Enter number to spam: ')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.textnow.com/login')

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('txt-username')
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('txt-password')
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login')
login_button.submit()

time.sleep(10)

Call_button = driver.find_element_by_id('newCall')
Call_button.submit()
```

Problem is that the `Call_button` doesn't open what it has to open. Nothing happens when it should open up the call dial box

Comment: What error do you see? Which line? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: It's not a error it just doesn't open the last function the ```Call_button```

Comment: Hard to debug the issue without any error trace. Are you sure the id is as what's in the code `newCall`. It could also be a frame issue - you can look into that too. Moreover, call(VOIP) protocol based interface are often protected/secture from web automation so that could also be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the detection method into xpath since that yields better results.

```
Call_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpathcode')
```